# Password Protect Excel Workbook from MS Access

Tags: excel, vba, ms-access, password-protection

I need to password protect entire workbook for opening. There's no need to protect the sheets as user will do some edits once reports are generated.Code runs within MS Access. Office Version is 2003. There's no possibility of using "SAVE AS" password protect method due to certain restrictions.

Can you please point out what I am doing wrong here?

Here's what I have tried so far:

```
Sub testProtection()
Dim xl As New Excel.Application
Dim wkbook As Workbook
Dim fileToOpen As String

    On Error GoTo ExitMe
    fileToOpen = "filepath & name"
    Set wkbook = xl.Workbooks.Open(fileToOpen)
```

**error in following lines: Automation Error Object invoked has disconnection from its client**

```
    wkbook.Protect Password:="100", Structure:=True, Windows:=True
    wkbook.Close savechanges:=True

ExitMe:

    MsgBox err.Description

    Set xl = Nothing
    Set wkbook = Nothing
    Call cleanAllXLInstances
End Sub
```

PS: It's an incentive if the workaround could be compatible with MS 2010 as the tools will be migrated in the future - but not mandatory at this point. Plus I could manage it when looking at the API later on if current code can be worked out.

Comment: you've got an exit sub before the `ExitMe` yea?

Comment: What prevents you from having a password protection on the workbook before you open it?

Comment: @cjb110 ?? Exit Sub???

Comment: @Juliusz can you show me a code that can be used to protect the workbook without opening it in VBA within MS Access?

Comment: At the moment your code will always print `err.Description` even if there is no error.  So you need an `Exit Sub` before the `ExitMe:` label.

Comment: @cjb110 That's expected! THAT MSGBOX is for testing, as you can see very well the sub name itself "testProtection". What are you talking about `Exit Sub`??? At the end infact there won't be any message boxes in my code, the errors will be logged into a log file.

Comment: I'm just checking that you are getting an actual error, and not just assuming that because the message box text looks like an error that it actually is.  In VB you would always have an `Exit Sub\Function` before any error handling block.

Comment: @cjb110 Well I doubt this question is tagged as VB... it's VBA

Comment: Those two are identical in this respect. See http://support.microsoft.com/kb/141571

Comment: @cjb110 thanks for all the irrelavant into and to be very polite to you, my question has nothing to do with what you are talking about. You are just commenting and you don't seem to answer the question... Plus I have gotten the answer I need by using "SAVE AS METHOD" And

Answer (score 0):

All I need to make sure, at this point **`Display Alerts = False` to suppress the alerts** for Saving As file with same name in same location. Which is contradictory to the initial constraints of the question asked though...

```
        If xlPwd <> 0 Then
            wkBook.SaveAs fileName:=fileToSaveAs, Password:=xlPwd, CreateBackup:=False
            wkBook.Close
            strMssg = " : Report is Protected!"
        Else
            strErrMssg = " : Report is NOT Protected!"
            isWrapped = False
            GoTo ExitMe
        End If
```